# check multiple files md5s in native c++

Tags: c++

guys whats problem with this source?
i use this to check MD5s but only first md5 checked?

```
if(md5("main\iw_00") != "92d86b9137f249a51ce14256362514bc"
              || md5("main\iw_01") != "80e13bc5fb2078728405bfae9b529414"
              || md5("main\iw_02") != "be2c0a1cbf5858e978dc39a8e00bff62"
              || md5("main\iw_03") != "223fc8672db4e0d3ef38f8348b9be6da"
              || md5("main\iw_04") != "8fde7ed770c6136039206edbb24f5b8a")
```

Comment: if the first condition is true, if statement should ignore the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Compare string literals by pointer is usually meaningless. Try `strcmp` or something like.

```
strcmp(md5("main\iw_01"), "80e13bc5fb2078728405bfae9b529414") != 0
```

Comment: Look for strcmp documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`main\iw01` is most probably not what you really want. `\` starts an escape sequence. In most cases the correct usage (especially since `\i` doesn't exist) would be `main\\iw01`.

Answer (score -1):

This condition is true all the time , you can not use ! and || togther .

Comment: The `md5` is computed for different arguments, so the condition may be false. And one can use `!` and `||` together, one just has to do it right.